# How to use incremental data to create dataframes in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, transpose

I have some tables in hive. These tables get data appended incrementally to them.

Now I have created a `data frame` in pyspark using a table in hive today. I have done a transpose on the `data frame` and created another table with the new transposed `data frame` in hive.

Say tomorrow I get new incremental data in hive table of 100  new rows. Now I want to use only these 100 new rows an create a new `data frame` and do a transpose and append to the existing transposed hive table.

How can I achieve that using pyspark.

Comment: Is there a way to identify those new 100 rows that have been added to the hive table. Can you easily create a new dataframe based on only those 100 rows??

Comment: @GauravDhama Yeah got a basic Idea how we can create data frame will try the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semantics in Hive in itself are not enough to provide this functionality.  The data either has to be identifiable via content, file, or metadata process.

**Identifiable by content:**  The data contains a time or date stamp which allows you to create a query against the table, but filter out only those rows that are of interest.

**Identifiable by file:**  Skip the Hive interface and attempt to locate the data on HDFS/POSIX using the `Modify` or `Change` timesteamps on individual files, for example.  Load the file directly as a new dataframe.

**Identifiable by metadata process:**  In the architecture I've built, I use Apache NiFi, Kafka and Cloudera Navigator to provide metadata lineage regarding file and data ingestion.  If your architecture contains metadata about  ingested data, you may be able to leverage that to identify the files/records you need.

Comment: Hi @JamCon, how can we obtain data ingestion lineage from Apache Nifi with Cloudera Navigator? I have not found any solution or come across any documentation for this.

Comment: @YayatiSule I haven't done the work with NiFi and Cloudera, to be honest.  The Data Lineage is available through NiFi APIs, I know, but I don't know if it's accessible through Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue here, and I was looking into the [Apache Hudi](https://hudi.apache.org/) solution, unfortunately the new incremental data needs to be stored via HUDI, so the metadata can be generated.
Here is a [quick guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hudi-work-with-dataset.html) on how to work with Hudi dataset in AWS environment.